# Append Null to `StringBuilder`

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stringbuilder

I'm reading from an XML file and building string using `StringBuilder`. But sometimes my `Element.Attributes` are missing in which case the string is null.

```
string key  = (string)EventId.Descendants("properties").Elements("ID").Attributes("key").FirstorDefault();
```

After getting all the attribue values I'm doing a string build:

```
sb.Append(key.PadRight(33));
```

But sometimes the value of `key` can be null, in which it gives an error:

> Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method

I want to append empty string to `StringBuilder` even if the value is null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply write

```
 sb.Append((key ?? "").PadRight(33));
```

The ?? is called the [Null-Coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

Its job consist in evaluating the left side value and, if this value is null, then return the right side value. Or in other words it is a shortcut for

```
sb.Append((key == null ? "" : key).PadRight(33));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for?

```
if (key != null)
    sb.Append(key.PadRight(33));
else
    sb.Append("".PadRight(33));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:
`sb.Append(key?.PadRight(33));`

Comment: This will not work. The PadRight(33) will not be evaluated if the key is null

Comment: Yes this works, i tried but padding is not working. I need the padding to maintain readability.